# Application to view and print calendar events in a list (using .ics files)

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, installed-programs

I use the Lightning extension in Mozilla Thunderbird for my calendars. I'd like to be able to view and print my calendar events in a list format like

```
DATE  Event
DATE  Event
DATE  Event
```

and so on. Is there any way to make Lighting do this? Or are there any other applications that could do this?

Comment: I am not sure about lightning, but you can do it in evolution calendar in list view. here is the [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/uhmhpuK.png). Install evolution using `sudo apt-get install evolution`

Answer (score 0):

The latest Thunderbird (31) in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS does include a list print format but it's not exactly as you want it.

It includes all details of an event, including the description. You can find the option under Print > Layout > List.